# Bounding the norm of the Laplacian of the gradient of a function having Lipschitz continuous Hessian

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

It seems that the following claim is true, but I did not manage to prove it neither to find a reference.

**Claim** Let $f:\mathbb R^p\to\mathbb R$ be a three times differentiable function such that its Hessian is Lipschitz continuous:
$$
\|\nabla^2 f(x)-\nabla^2 f(y)\|\le M\|x-y\|\qquad\forall x,y\in\mathbb R^p,
$$
where the matrix norm is the largest singular value while the vector norm is the usual Euclidean norm. Then, for every $x\in\mathbb R^p$ we have
$$
\|\boldsymbol\Delta [\nabla f(x)]\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^p \bigg(
\sum_{j=1}^p \frac{\partial^3 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j^2} (x)\bigg)^2 \le pM^2.
$$

I can prove such an inequality with $p^2M^2$ instead of $pM^2$, but do not see how one can remove one power of $p$.

Comment: Check the proof of Lemma 6 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.00095.pdf

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent formulation of the claim is the following. If the Hessian of a 3 times differentiable fnction $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with constant $M$, then the Laplacian of $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with the constant $M\sqrt{p}$.

Answer (score -1):

The claim is false. The counter example is the function 
$f(x) = \varphi(\|x\|_2)$ with an increasing and infinitely differentiable
function $\varphi:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ satisfying
$$
\varphi(t) = 
\begin{cases}
t^4,& \text{if } t\le 1,\\
2, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
There is also the example with 
$$
\varphi(t) = 
\begin{cases}
31t^2 ,& \text{if } t\le 1,\\
3t^6-20.8t^5+51t^4-56t^3+56t^2-2.2, &\text{if } t\in[1,2],\\
96t-75.8&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
The resulting function $f$ is then convex, since the function $\varphi$ is convex and increasing.

Comment: Your first $\varphi$ is discontinuous.